# Can the Success Chance be cheesed?

Tags: prison-architect

I am trying to earn the "The Reform through Education Initiative" grant. To do that, at least one prisoner must pass, not just finish, the "General Education Qualification" course. This is already hard to achieve since it is a much more difficult course than its pre-requirement, and the prisoners who are qualified are usually released before they can sign up.

At the moment, I have a single prisoner enrolled in the course, and his Sucess Chance is lower than the tenth percentile. What I am hoping will work is an idea that I have to cheese the system.

If I were to save the prison right before the course ended, and then reload the prison if the prison hadn't passed, then I would be able to get the grant significantly sooner than if I were to wait for another prisoner to qualify just to have another low chance at passing.

I am not sure if "soft resetting" will work in this case. Before I waste a long time farming for this one prisoner to pass, I would like to know if this method is even feasible, or if the game is hardwired to fail the prisoner if the Sucess Chance is lower than a certain threshold.

Is this a viable method?

Comment: Since time is a factor causing you to fail getting the achievement, can you not get prisoners with longer sentences for this?

Comment: @BenOng Unless I am missing something, the sentence lengths are random for each prisoner. If there is a way to manipulate it, that might be easier, but it would still be very time-consuming.

Comment: yup, higher security prisoners have longer sentences. There is even a possibility of life sentence but those are really not worth taking. So I can't answer your question about cheesing the success rate, but you can get the achievement using higher sec prisoners for more time to complete the course.